# Как перевернуть изображение WinAPI C

Tags: c, winapi, изображения

Дан одномерный массив пикселей изображения. Необходимо их перевернуть на 90 градусов и создать новое bmp изображение. Я это делаю посредством заполнения двумерного массива, преобразований в нем и обратно заполнения одномерного массива на выходе, но у меня получается вот такое:

[image]

Вот функция:

```
HBITMAP RotateBitmap(HBITMAP srcBitmap) {


    BITMAP bitmap;
    HBITMAP dstBitmap;
    unsigned char *bits;
    unsigned char *pBits;
    unsigned char *newBits;
    unsigned char *pNewBits;
    unsigned char **tmpBits;
    unsigned char **rotBits;
    unsigned int pixelCount;
    unsigned int bytesPixel;
    int i, j;


    if (!GetObject(srcBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &bitmap)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    if ((bitmap.bmBitsPixel != 24) && (bitmap.bmBitsPixel != 32)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    pixelCount = bitmap.bmHeight * bitmap.bmWidth;

    bytesPixel = bitmap.bmBitsPixel / 8;

    bits = (unsigned char*)malloc(bitmap.bmWidthBytes * bitmap.bmHeight);
    if (!bits) {
        return NULL;
    }

    newBits = (unsigned char*)malloc(bitmap.bmWidthBytes * bitmap.bmHeight);
    if (!newBits) {
        return NULL;
    }

    GetBitmapBits(srcBitmap, bitmap.bmBitsPixel * pixelCount, (void*)bits);

    pBits = bits;
    pNewBits = newBits;

    //Запись пикселей в двумерный массив
    tmpBits = (unsigned char**)malloc(bitmap.bmHeight);
    if (!tmpBits) {
        return NULL;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.bmHeight; ++i) {
        tmpBits[i] = (unsigned char*)malloc(bitmap.bmWidthBytes);
        if (!tmpBits[i]) {
            return NULL;
        }
        pBits = bits + i * bitmap.bmWidthBytes;
        for (j = 0; j < bitmap.bmWidthBytes; ++j) {
            tmpBits[i][j] = *pBits;
            pBits += 1;
        }
    }

    //Массив перевернутых пикселей
    rotBits = (unsigned char**)malloc(bitmap.bmWidthBytes);
    if (!rotBits) {
        return NULL;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < bitmap.bmWidthBytes; ++i) {
        rotBits[i] = (unsigned char*)malloc(bitmap.bmHeight);
        if (!rotBits[i]) {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    //Заполняем массив
    for (i = 0; i < bitmap.bmWidthBytes; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < bitmap.bmHeight; ++j) {
            rotBits[i][bitmap.bmHeight - 1 - j] = tmpBits[j][i];
        }
    }

    //Возвращаем полученный двумерный массив перевернутых пикселей в одномерный
    for (i = 0; i < bitmap.bmWidthBytes; ++i) {
        pNewBits = newBits + i * bitmap.bmHeight;
        for (j = 0; j < bitmap.bmHeight; ++j) {
            *pNewBits = rotBits[i][j];
            pNewBits += 1;
        }
    }

    //Создаем изображение
    dstBitmap = CreateBitmap(bitmap.bmHeight, bitmap.bmWidth, 1, bitmap.bmBitsPixel, newBits);

    free(bits);
    free(newBits);

    return dstBitmap;
}
```

В WinAPI я совершенно не разбираюсь, но задание срочно нужно сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Александр! Хорошо, что Вы задаете вопросы, чтобы выполнить задание, я Вам подскажу. Попробуйте использовать такой цикл в функции

```
for (i = 0; i < bitmap.bmHeight; ++i) {
    pBits = bits + i * bitmap.bmWidthBytes;
    for (j = 0; j < bitmap.bmWidth; ++j) {
        pmyBits = myBits + (bitmap.bmHeight - i - 1) * bytesPixel + j * bitmap.bmHeight*bytesPixel;
        memcpy(pmyBits, pBits, bytesPixel);
        pBits += bytesPixel;
    }
}
```

Встретимся в среду, надеюсь все получится